# Play a new file format on old TV and DVD player

Tags: laptop, audio, video, hdmi, tv

I want to play movies of newer file formats on my DVD player (home theater) and TV. However, both had been purchased around 2011, when no x265, mkv, etc support were made available on those devices.

Forums suggest connecting HDMI cables to those devices from the PC, and playing the actual video on the PC. So... the PC will do the actual work, while (I suppose) that the TV will be a big monitor and the DVD player will be a big soundbox.

1] Is this possible?
2] Also, my TV has 2 hdmi ports, while my PC and DVD player have 1 port each. What kind of configuration may I make for the wires so that I can use all 3 devices (PC, TV and DVD Player) at the same time?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Another option would be to be buy a chomecast. Otherwise, yeah, just connect the PC and TV together so it acts as a monitor. Or buy a raspberry pi and mount it to the back of tv and wireless grab the video files.

Comment: If it's the video formats that are the main problem (i.e. if you can play other video formats on the DVD player) you could just try converting the files to a supported format